# Which is better and faster ? Wordpress Queries or SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, single

Suppose I am developing a minimal theme, the the post page `single.php` displays only the post title, the excerpt and the content.

So in general that would be

```
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

So I am expecting 3 queries...

Instead if I write a custom query where I am just fetching these 3 datas in an array at once...

```
<?php arr[] = get_row(select title, excerpt, content from wp_posts where post_id = 1); ?>
<?php echo arr[0] ?>
<?php echo arr[1] ?>
<?php echo arr[2] ?>
```

Which is faster or does it make a difference ?

Plz ignore syntax if wrong...

Comment: There are no native database queries in the WordPress functions `the_title()`, `the_excerpt()` and `the_content()`. You should profile your theme to  better see where the queries come from. Many good tools out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Queries ofcourse. It's faster...

But in this case just please delete you wp site and start with something *faster*... 
here is my superfast framework for you...

```
<?php 
/*Your bunny wrote */
```

I did tests, 0.0000001 runtime vs WP usually 0.7-2.8

**Sarcasm off**

P/S/
This question have no sence since using direct queries and output of the variables isn't use advantages of the WP. Author obviosly CAN do that, but I am wandering why to use WP and not using all positive things of it.